# How to use the same R recode function on multiple variables without coding each?

Tags: r, tidyverse, recode

From the recode examples, what if I have two variables where I want to apply the same recode?

```
factor_vec1 <- factor(c("a", "b", "c"))
factor_vec2 <- factor(c("a", "d", "f"))
```

How can I recode the same answer without writing a recode for each `factor_vec`? These don't work, do I need to learn how to use `purrr` to do it, or is there another way?

```
Output 1: recode(c(factor_vec1, factor_vec2), a = "Apple")
Output 2: recode(c(factor_vec2, factor_vec2), a = "Apple", b = 
"Banana")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lists to hold multiple vectors and then you can apply same function using `lapply`/`map`.

```
library(dplyr)
list_fac <- lst(factor_vec1, factor_vec2)
list_fac <- purrr::map(list_fac, recode, a = "Apple", b = "Banana")
```

You can keep the vectors in list itself (which is better) or get the changed vectors in global environment using `list2env`.

```
list2env(list_fac, .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 2):

If there are not many items needed to be recoded, you can try a simple lookup table approach using base R.

```
v1 <- c("a", "b", "c")
v2 <- c("a", "d", "f")

# lookup table 
lut <- c("a" ="Apple", 
         "b" = "Banana",
         "c" = "c",
         "d" = "d", 
         "f" = "f")

lut[v1]
lut[v2]
```

You can reuse the lookup table for any relevant variables. The results are:

```
> lut[v1]
       a        b        c 
 "Apple" "Banana"      "c" 

> lut[v2]
      a       d       f 
"Apple"     "d"     "f"
```